# Rendering a partial from javascript, Issue with passing class variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to set up a view with infinite scroll.  I'm doing that by having javascript load a partial, but the problem is I need to pass in the variable @row (see the partial below) to calculate which objects to load.

The @row variable doesn't load when the partial is inserted via the js below.

Am I approaching this problem wrong (is there an easier way to insert rails objects), or is there a way to pass the @row variable into the partial from js.

Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

The js loaded from the controller response above:

```
$(' #{render "shared/browse_row" ).insertAfter( $('.row') );
```

View:

```
-(1..6).each do
    = render "shared/browse_row"
```

browse_row partial:

```
.row{'data-row'=> "#{@row}"}
-@row += 1
%ul
    -@i = 0
    -project_row( @row ).each do |project|
        -@i += 1
        -@i == 4 ? right = "right" : right = ""
        %li{:class => right}
            = image_tag( project.display_pic.url(:medium) )
            .filler{'data-link' => '/projects/'+project.id.to_s }
                .filler-text
                    .p-name
                        = project.name
                        .p-creator= "by " + project.creator.name
                    .p-price= "$" + number_with_precision(project.price, :precision => 2).to_s
                    .p-days
                        - if days_left( project ) > 0
                            ="Expires in " + pluralize( days_left( project ), " Day")
                        - else
                            ="Expires Today"
                    .p-percent
                        - percent_funded(project).gsub("%","").to_i > 100 ? percent = "100%" : percent = percent_funded(project)
                        .p-percent-bar{:style => "width:#{ percent };"}
```

Comment: it is a railscast about this [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page)

Comment: what was it called, i'm a little lost not sure what words i'd search for

Comment: The "modern" approach is to make the server return JSON and render the HTML view client-side, it's cleaner. But I guess you'll prefer not to change things at this moment...

Comment: if you have pro account on railscast take a look at [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/295-sharing-mustache-templates)

Comment: @tokland thanks i ended up doing it with json like you said, worked beautifully

Comment: @Alex: Great! The logic-view isolation that this approach gives you is certainly rewarding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the `@row` instance variable into the partial when you render it using this syntax:

```
render :partial => "shared/browse_row", :locals => { :row => @row }
```

It will then be available in the `browse_row` partial file as a variable named `row`

So then you'd just change it to this:

```
.row{'data-row'=> "#{row}"}
```

---

In the future, you may want to do something more like this...

In the link to load more projects:

```
<a href="path_to/more_projects" class="get-new-projects" data-remote="true" data-method="GET">Load more projects</a>
```

In your controller file:

```
def show
  row = params[:row]
  @projects = Project.where('id > ?', row)  

  render :json => { :projects => render_to_string( :partial => 'shared/browse_row.html',
                                                   :locals => { :row => row }) }, 
         :status => :ok
end
```

Then in your ajax success callback:

```
$('.get-new-projects').live('ajax:success', function(data, json, response) {
  // insert the rendered HTML that we passed in as a JSON string
  $('.row').after(json.projects);
});
```

This way, you keep everything nice and organized.  Your backend renders the code, your front end places the rendered code where it needs to be on the page... everyone is happy.

Comment: great post, thanks a lot, as a rails newbie i didn't realize i'd have to pass the partial back via json (i actually ended up passing the objects via json, but now I know I can return the rendered partial via json)  Thanks!